# Correct way of calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, marker

I am trying to extend the google maps marker example from the this [website](http://jay.f2fsolutions.net/21690) by adding the extraction of the country name.

Since google maps returns an array with details to each address, I need to iterate over the array to find the entry e.g. for "country". Since I would like to reuse the piece of code, I create a function.

But I am not sure how to call this function (here call **find(components, item)**) correctly.

I do not get any return from the find function. **How do I call the find function correctly from within the select function?**
**Could there be a different mistake why I get an empty return?**

Thank you for your thoughts and suggestions!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

initialize();

$(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
        //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
        source: function(request, response) {
            geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
                response($.map(results, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label:  item.formatted_address,
                    value: item.formatted_address,
                    components: item.address_components,
                    latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                    longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                    }
                }));
            })
        },

        // address_component selection
        find: function(components, item) {
            for(var j=0;j < components.length; j++){
                for(var k=0; k < components[j].types.length; k++){
                    if(components[j].types[k] == "country"){
                        return components[j].long_name;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

    //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        $("#country").val(this.find(ui.item.components, "country"));
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have nested document ready functions? (You've got `$(document).ready(function() {` and then two lines later the equivalent statement `$(function() {`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find()` function is defined in the `autocomplete` options object.

If you want to access your find function you'll have to define it outside the autocomplete options or to get a pointer to it :

```
var find = $(event.target).data("autocomplete").options.find;
```

This is because jQuery changes the context of functions with the element that is attached to the listener.

Comment: Thank you. I moved the function outside of the autocomplete function and it works as you wrote. Thank you for the hint!